# jQuery.ajax and XMLHttpRequest()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve and execute the script contained in a file "example.js", using an AJAX request.

Let's say the example.js is:

```
const greetings = {
    hello: "Hello",
    goodBye: "Good bye"
}
console.log(greetings.hello)
```

In another file, "get_script.js", I try to execute the code above using AJAX.

The request and execution is working just perfect with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    async: false,
    url: "example.js",
    success: function (response) {
      new Function(response)
    }
});

console.log(greetings.goodBye)

//output in the console:
// "hello"    - from example.js
// "goodbye"  - from get_script.js
```

while with a new XMLHttpRequest(), it doesn't:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const fn = new Function(xhr.response)
        fn();
    }
}
xhr.open("GET" , "example.js" , false);
xhr.send();

console.log(greetings.goodBye)


// the file is retrieved without problems.
//output in the console:
// "hello"     - still getting the console.log() from example.js! 
//               So the script is executed, right?
// Uncaught ReferenceError: greetings is not defined
```

Notes:

- in the XMLHttpRequest the function only execute if I store it in a variable and then call it.
- I experienced that the async set to false is not the reason of this inequality.

Did I write something wrong in the second code? Can anybody explain the reason of this difference?

Thanks so much in advance!

EDIT 04/08/2022

Looking at the jQuery's functions I found out that their way to automatically execute the retrieved code is to append a script tag with the retrieved code as text and then immediately remove it.
I did that in my code and worked just as $.get():

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const script = document.createElement("script")
        script.text = xhr.response;  
        document.head
            .appendChild(script)
            .parentNode
            .removeChild(script);
    }
}
xhr.open("GET" , "example.js" , false);
xhr.send();

console.log(greetings.goodBye)

//output in the console:
// "hello"    - from example.js
// "goodbye"  - from get_script.js
```

Apparently this is how jQuery does it.
Hope I didn't make any mistakes.

**Thanks to user Musa for leading me to the solution!**

Answer (score 1):

The $.ajax call executed the script(like if it was in a `<script>` tag) defining `greetings` as a global constant and logging the value. The function you created in $.ajax success callback is never executed so is insignificant.

The XHR call does not execute the js, but you do it manually with the `fn` function.
The problem here is that the constant `greetings`' scope is limited to the `fn` function and not global.

Comment: Why does `$.ajax` execute scripts without being told to do?

Comment: Oh [I see](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): "*If [no `dataType`] is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response*"

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Just out of curiosity: Is there a (simple) way I can achieve what jQuery does, with the regular XMLHttpRequest? Or is it something bigger than me? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but to achieve what's happening with jQuery you can just have the js included in a script tag. `<script src="example.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, it was mostly curiosity. I think I found out that jQuery, in order to execute the code retrieved by $.get(), create a <script> element, set its text property with the retrieved code, append the tag to the head and then immediately remove it. I did the same and it worked, I could dynamically execute the code without writing the script tag